# How can I sort strings (in my case players) that have an associated integer (I have a grade for them)?

Tags: string, sorting, integer

I have ratings for different player which are strings. I am able to sort the ratings but I cannot keep the players with the rating. What data structure should I use...? I tried a linked list but was not successful. Maybe a hash table?

The following is the main function I am working with:

```
playerData::playerData(string fileInput){
//header.next = &trailer;
trailer.prev = &header;
ifstream file(fileInput);
 if (file.is_open())
{
    while(file.good()){
        getline(file, player, ',');
        //file >> name;
        file >> position;
        file >> min;
        file >> fgPercent;
        file >> ftPercent;
        file >> threePM;
        file >> rebound;
        file >> assist;
        file >> steals;
        file >> blocks;
        file >> TOPG;
        file >> points;
        /*
        cout << player <<  "; Position: " << position << "; MPG: " << min << "; FG%: " << fgPercent << 
        "; FT%: " << ftPercent << "; 3PM: " << threePM << "; RPG: " << rebound << "; APG: " << assist << 
        "; STPG: " << steals << "; BLKPG: " << blocks << "; TOPG: " << TOPG << "; PTS: " << points;
        */
        cout << player <<  "; Position: " << position;
        rating = (fgPercent * 30) + (ftPercent * 18) + (threePM * 15) + (rebound * 3) + (assist * 2) + (steals * 10) + (blocks * 15) - (TOPG * 3.5) + (points * 0.7);
        cout << "; RATING: " << rating;

        //if(header.next == &trailer){
            
        //}
    }
}
else
{
    cout << "Error opening file" << endl;
}
cout << endl;
```

}

This will output players with their given ratings. I was going to copy the output file which has the player's name and their rating to another dat file then run it another function which will sort the ratings with the associated player. I am working with C++.

Comment: please post what you have tried so far, the language you are working on, and a minimal reproducible example

Comment: i have made some edits. I am coding in C++